# Session Variables Query

Tags: php, session

My application has three generalised functions. They are registering, login and then viewing profile page. Registering is working fine. As soon as you login you will be directed to profile page. So when directed to the profile page, if your session variables are set, then the links in the header must change.

If they are not set they will show Register and Login. The problem here is, when I login my links in the header are not changing. They are still showing Register and Login. The profile page is showing all the details of the user like country, state, city etc., but not username (which I'm getting using the session variables). I think something is wrong with my session variables.

Here's the code snippet of my profile page.

```
<?php
session_start(); // Must start session first thing
// See if they are a logged in member by checking Session data
$toplinks = "";
$username = "";
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    // Put stored session variables into local php variable
    //$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    //$username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $userid = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION['id']);
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
    $toplinks = '<a href="memberprofile.php?id=' . $userid . '">' . $username . '</a> &bull; 
    <a href="memberaccount.php">Account</a> &bull; 
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
} else {
    $toplinks = '<a href="register.php">Register</a> &bull; <a href="login.php">Login</a>';
}
?>
```

I had to declare `$username = "";` at the beginning because if I don't, a notice is being display saying undefined index.

I'm setting my session variables in the login page. I'm sure that the control is by passing the if block and entering else block. I'm fairly new to php and any help is appreciated.

P.S: I'm using ajax to interact between pages.

Comment: i think you miss $_SESSION['userid'] in if condition $_SESSION['id'] also try to print_r($_SESSION) before your if() so you will what is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `print_r($_SESSION)` after your `session_start()` function..
and check what values are you getting in `session variables`

and let me know...

Comment: Array() is being printed at the top left corner of the page.

Comment: ohh your `sesssion array ` is empty... when you are setting `session variables` you have forgot to `start the session` please put `session_start()` on the top of your `login check` page...

Answer (score 1):

Change your line from

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

to

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) && isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

Comment: I'm sorry i posted the question wrongly before. Now I have made the changes. I even tested my code. It is not entering the if block

Comment: try putting `var_dump($_SESSION);` before if condition & check what values you are getting

Comment: I'm getting  array(0) { }.

Comment: that means problem in session storing values. Please update your code hows you store values in session after login. & put `session_start();` at the top of your login page